# Count number of rows in a section until the blank line

Tags: google-docs

I've got a spreadsheet in google docs that looks like#

```
2010  <X>
Row1
Row2
Row3
Row4

1999 <Y>
Row1
Row2
Row3
Row4
Row5
Row6
```

Where X is 4 as there are for rows in 2010 section followed by a blank line. Y is 6 as there are 6 rows till the end of the document.

I did try

```
=filter(row(A:A), A:A="",row(A:A)<=max(filter(row(A:A),A:A<>"")))
```

and

```
=filter(row($A:$A),(len($A:$A)=0)*(row($A:$A)>row()))-row()-1
```

They all return

> error: Mismatched range lengths

What could be done in this case? Using named section is really time-consuming as there will be up to 100 sections.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if would be best to store your data like this instead:

```
        A         B      C
--------------------------
 1|     2010    Row1    <X>
 2|     2010    Row2
 3|     2010    Row3
 4|     2010    Row4
 5|
 6|     1999    Row1    <Y>
 7|     1999    Row2
 8|     1999    Row3
 9|     1999    Row4
10|     1999    Row5
11|     1999    Row6
```

because then `X` and `Y` can be calulated simply as: `=countif(A:A,A1)` and `=countif(A:A,A6)`

---

if you have to persist with your setup

```
         A        B 
--------------------------
 1|     2010    <X>
 2|     Row1    
 3|     Row2    
 4|     Row3    
 5|     Row4
 6|             
 7|     1999    <Y>
 8|     Row1    
 9|     Row2    
10|     Row3    
11|     Row4    
12|     Row5    
13|     Row6
```

then you can use:
`=ArrayFormula(match(1,--(ISBLANK(A1:A13)),0)-2)`
(as long as there is always an empty row between the sets of "Years"

- the `ISBLANK(A1:A13)` return an array result {FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,...}
- the `--` changes that to: {0,0,0,0,0,1,0...}
- the `match()` returns the POSITION or ROW of the first `1` in that list : 6
- we then take away 2, for the empty row and for the header row
- we have to run the whole thin as an array formula because we need ISBLANK() to work on each cell in turn.

Comment: Great, thank you! Although double-minus did not work for me and returned the parse error. I used TRUE directly in the values to match against. So it looked like =ArrayFormula(match(TRUE,ISBLANK(A1:A13),0)-2)